# Detect the position,orientation and color in Matlab of not overlapped Tiles to be picked by robot

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on a project where I need to find the 
square shape tiles in pile which are not overlapped,
 am currently working on a project where
 I need to determine the orientation , position (center ) ,and color
 of each square tile . These orientation and positions
will be used as input for a robot to be picked 
and the robot will sort them in a specific  locations  . 
 I am using Matlab and i should transfer the data using TCP/IP. 
I've experimenting with edge detection(canny,sobel) ,
found the boundaries,segmentation using threshold and FCM but 
I haven't found a reliable way to determine the tiles which are 
not overlapped ,i am trying to use template shape matching but
 i don't know how  to do that . This needs to be done in real time 
as i will be using frame which is taken from a USB camera that 
attached to PC .  I was wondering if someone could offer a
 reliable solution ?  Here is a sample image.
I was wondering if someone could offer 
a reliable solution to determine the square shape tiles
 which are not overlapped?  Here is a sample image[overlapped Tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOVl8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You've separated the image into tiles and background. So now simply label all the connected components. Take each one and test for single tile-ness. If you know the approximate size of the tiles, first exclude by area. Then calculate the centroid and the extreme left, right, top and bottom. If it is tile, the intersection of top bottom and left-right will be approximately in the centroid, and the half angles will be perpendicular to the tile edge. So rotate, take the bounding box, and count unset pixels, which should be almost zero for a rectangluar tile.

(You'll probably need to do a morphological operation or two to clean up the images if the tile / background separation is a bit dicey).

Check out the binary image processing library http://malcolmmclean.github.io/binaryimagelibrary [1](http://malcolmmclean.github.io/binaryimagelibrary/)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your quick replay.i already did some morphological operation and found connected component and below is  my code in matlab ,and each tile has 2.5*2.5 cm area

```
    a = imread('origenal image.jpg');
    I = rgb2gray(a);
    imshow(I)
    thresold = graythresh(I);
    se1=strel('diamond',2);
    I1=imerode(I,se1);
    figure(1)
    imshow(I1);
    bw = imclose(I1 , ones(25) );
    imshow(bw)
    CC = bwconncomp(bw);
    L = labelmatrix(CC);
```